# Testing results of an initial ajax request with Jasmine 2.0

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, jasmine, backbone-views, jasmine-jquery

I am testing a Backbone View with Jasmine 2.0. The View makes an initial ajax request on load to populate its form field with values. I want my Jasmine test (in the `it` function below) to run only after those values are received.

The test currently fails because it seems the ajax request is received after the test runs, even though I am stubbing the ajax request.

How should I be writing this test?

```
describe('View', function() {

  var formFieldValues = [/* blah */];
  var view;

  beforeEach(function(done) {
    jasmine.Ajax.install();
    jasmine.Ajax.stubRequest('/form-fields').andReturn({
      responseJSON: formFieldValues
    });
    view = new View({el: $('<main></main>')}); // makes ajax call on initialization
    $('body').append(view.el);
  });

  afterEach(function() {
    view.remove();
    jasmine.Ajax.uninstall();
  });

  it('form fields have values', function(done) {
    // PROBLEM IS HERE: THE FOLLOWING RUNS BEFORE VIEW'S AJAX CALL FINISHES
    expect(view.$('[name="fieldName"]').children().length).toEqual(formFieldValues.length);
  });

});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't look like you're actually running async specs. I notice your `beforeEach` and `it` both receive a `done` callback, but neither of them call that. And if you're stubbing out ajax, then you probably don't need to be running an async spec, because the stub will 
effectively make the ajax request be synchronous.

When I run the following code, everything works fine.

Spec:

```
describe('View', function() {

  var formFieldValues = [{name: 'foo'}, {name: 'bar'}];
  var view;

  beforeEach(function() {
    jasmine.Ajax.install();
    jasmine.Ajax.stubRequest('/form-fields').andReturn({
      responseText: JSON.stringify(formFieldValues)
    });
    view = new View(); // makes ajax call on initialization
  });

  afterEach(function() {
    jasmine.Ajax.uninstall();
  });

  it('form fields have values', function() {
    // PROBLEM IS HERE: THE FOLLOWING RUNS BEFORE VIEW'S AJAX CALL FINISHES
    expect(view.$('[name="fieldName"]').children().length).toEqual(formFieldValues.length);
  });

});
```

My dummy implementation:

```
Collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  url: '/form-fields'
});

View = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function() {
    this.collection = new Collection();
    this.collection.on('reset', this.render, this);
    this.collection.fetch({reset: true});
  },

  render: function() {
    var innerEl = $('<div name="fieldName"></div>')
    this.collection.each(function(item) {
      innerEl.append('<span></span>');
    });
    this.$el.append(innerEl);
  }
});
```

Comment: Your code does work, and it helped me to fix an issue with my own, so I will probably reward you the points. But I still have a strange problem: I trigger a "change" event which actually sets up the field values initially, but I am seeing in a debugger that Backbone's "delegateEvents" is run after my change is triggered, which seems to be the root problem. This doesn't happen the live site but only in the Jasmine tests.

Comment: Backbone calls into delegateEvents at the very end of the constructor, if you got yourself into some kind of callback crazytown, and your change event is being triggered while the view is still constructing itself, that could happen. Without seeing what the change event looks like and where it's running, it's hard to help debug it though.

Answer (score 0):

The **runs() and waitFor() Methods** should be used to make it asynchronous.
Calls to run() methods act as individual testing blocks, the last of which would make the asynchronous call. In the simplest case, a setTimeout() can be used to simulate asynchronous behavior. In a more complex usage, an actual call would be made, such as to an Ajax-enabled object.

The waitsFor() method accepts three arguments: "latch" function, failure message, timeout (in milliseconds)

```
runs(function() {
    flag = false;
    value = 0;

setTimeout(function() {
  value++;
  //keep returning false…
  flag = false;
}, 500);
  });

  waitsFor(function() {
    return flag;
  }, "The Value should be incremented", 5000);
});
```

Or u can try 
Making Real Ajax Requests

When it comes time to perform integration testing, you'll probably want to execute real Ajax calls rather than just mimic them. No problem. Just create a spy, make the Ajax call, followed by waitsFor(), where you can check the callback.callCount property or what-have-you:
?
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21

```
it("should make a real AJAX request", function () {
    var callback = jasmine.createSpy();
    makeAjaxCall(callback);
    waitsFor(function() {
        return callback.callCount > 0;
    }, "The Ajax call timed out.", 5000);

    runs(function() {
        expect(callback).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});

function makeAjaxCall(callback) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "data.json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
        dataType: "json",
        success: callback
    });
}
```

Comment: "runs" and "waitsFor" seem to be part of pre-Jasmine 2.0.

Comment: Then I think there should be something similar in Jasmine 2.0 as well.

Comment: Jasmine 2.0 introduced a `done` callback in case you really need a spec to actually be asynchronous. In the case of making an ajax request, you'll get more consistent (and faster) results by mocking out the ajax call and having it return synchronously in test.